# is there way to show preview of outlook email body in winform application

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption, addin-express

is there way to show exact preview of outlook email body in a windows form using office dlls and outlook plugin ?
it can be achieved using web-browser control by getting the body content.
but i need to show exact same preview such as new outlook explorer without elements other than the body  content

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What language/framework are you using? Why do you need to replicate native outlook functionality in an outlook add-in?! Why not build your extension onto the existing outlook email viewer?

Comment: @sasfrog as mentioned embedding a webbrowser into winform/wpf  is a one solution. there are circumstances to show preview of recipients email before sending. Ex- mail merge

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Most probably you will have to edit the HTML markup a bit before displaying it in the web browser. For example, a web browser doesn't understand embedded attachments displayed in the body (see for the `cid:` attribute in `img` elements).

Note, Outlook still uses Word for displaying the message body. Read more about

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12))
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))